# Per-user DNS settings for VPN

Tags: iptables, dns, openvpn, vpn, dynamic-linking

My system's set to send only a particular user's traffic through a vpn (via iptables and `--uid-owner`). It works fine, but that user's DNS leaks onto the open net.

Any way to send only one user's DNS through a VPN?

All solutions are welcome, from iptables to loading a custom library with `LD_PRELOAD`, etc.

(P.S. I followed this [guide](https://www.niftiestsoftware.com/2011/08/28/making-all-network-traffic-for-a-linux-user-use-a-specific-network-interface/), but in my system DNS doesn't have `--uid-owner` info attached - or so testing suggests)

Comment: Who is doing the DNS requests on your system? Do you have a local resolver? Do you use a resolution daemon like lwresd, nscd, unscd?